# storing different structs in an array

Tags: c, dictionary, struct

I tried to make an array that stores different structs and failed to do so.
Is it possible to store different structs in a single array? if not, is there a dictionary data structure in C?

This is what i have:

```
struct A {
    int row;
    int col;
};
struct B {
    int row;
    int col;
};

struct A bishop;
struct B rook;

bishop.row = 1;
bishop.col = 1;
rook.row = 2;
rook.col = 2;

arr[2] = {bishop,rook};
```

what data type do I need to give the array?

Comment: flexible array members are as close as you get in C.

Comment: How or where do these structs exist?  If its global or allocated then just use an array of pointers...You would a basic structure something like struct { void* pData, enum eSomeType id; }  then when you have an array of these elements where the pData points to your structure and the id describes the type.

Comment: No, basically you cannot. **All array elements must be of the same type**. If you can do with storing **pointers** or a *higher-level* `union` (`union manystruct { struct s1 s1; struct s2 s2; ...; struct sN sN; };`), it may be possible.

Comment: *"Is it possible to store different structs in a single array?"* - Yes, by using pointers or unions.

Comment: What does _different structs_ mean? Different types? In that case consider using an union, if you don't like @SPlatten 's suggestion.

Comment: Yes, you can. But you need something to distinguish between them.

Comment: @ryyker added some code, have a look

Comment: @DarkLeader, Why you even have two structs ? You can use one only because the fields are identical

Comment: @Youssef13 I'm making a chess game, each piece has a different movement pattern, I didn't add all of the attributes

Comment: @DarkLeader, Still, you can make **only one** struct. and add an enum field for example to determine the piece type.

Comment: @Youssef13 what about the movement of the piece? how will that work?

Comment: A struct has nothing to do with the **behavior** of the pieces. It holds only the **state**. You should handle the movement in a function whether it's in the main or another function. The struct will have an enum field to determine what piece it is to help your function determine the movement.

Comment: @Youssef13 aren't structs basically bad classes? I thought I could add the attributes I need directly

Comment: structs contain only fields, not methods. You can't have a function inside of your struct. So, you need to add a field to determine the piece type, and validate the moves based on the value of that field.

Comment: @Youssef13 thanks, thank you all.

Comment: @DarkLeader Structs are VERY bad classes. In general, don't try to mimic OOP in C. If you really need OOP, choose another language.

Comment: @klutt what if im stuck with C for now..?

Comment: @DarkLeader There is no problem that really *requires* OOP. ;)

Comment: @klutt sure but it will be a nightmare to create some things without oop

Comment: @DarkLeader It's often an even bigger nightmare to try to mimic oop in a language that does not support it. Using pointers or unions for this is an option, but it's often a sign that it would be wise to completely rethink what you are doing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Arrays contain data structures of the same type.  So you can't put two different structures in an array.

What you can do however is create another struct that contains the other two:

```
struct A_B {
    struct A a;
    struct B b;
};

...

struct A_B ab = { bishop, rook };
```

What I suspect you *actually* need is a common structure that can model all pieces like this:

```
enum piece_type {
     PAWN,
     KNIGHT,
     BISHOP,
     ROOK,
     QUEEN,
     KING
};

struct piece {
    enum piece_type type;
    int row;
    int col;
};

...

struct piece bishop = { BISHOP, 1, 1 };
struct piece rook = { ROOK, 2, 2 };

struct piece arr[2] = {bishop,rook};
```

This way you have an `enum` field which tells you what type the piece is to allow you to operate on it as appropriate.

Comment: I keep getting "error: a label can only be part of a statement and a declaration is not a statement" when i create a piece like you wrote "struct piece bishop = { BISHOP, 1, 1 };". any idea why? or a fix?

Comment: @DarkLeader You mistyped something.  Most likely a stray colon (`:`) which normally comes after a label.

Comment: case 'k':
                    struct piece blackKing = {KING,i,j,};
                    pieces[index] = blackKing;

Comment: I'm adding the structs to an array called pieces. and this is in a switch case block

Comment: @DarkLeader You can't declare a variable right before a case label.  You'll need to either create a new block scope or move the variable above the `switch`.

Comment: I need to use a switch case or alot of if statements. are you sure I can't you switch case?

Comment: @DarkLeader You can use a `switch`, you just can't declare a variable immediately after a case label.  You need to either move it or create a new block with `{` and `}`.

Answer (score 1):

The latest edit in your original post clarifies things.  You are really asking if an array of `struck` is possible.  (not an array of *different* `struct`.)

Yes, what you have describe in your edit can be accomplished in several ways.  The following method simply uses a `typedef` with `enum` and includes some possible naming improvements:

```
typedef struct {
    int row;
    int col;
}BLACK, WHITE;


BLACK black[16];
WHITE white[16];
```

Now you have 2 arrays of 16 instances, BLACK and WHITE chess pieces, each instance can hold different values, but are the same in every other way.

Now you can use an enum to help delineate each array member:

```
enum {
   KING,
   QUEEN,
   BISHOP,
   KNIGHT,
   ROOK,
   PAWN
};
```

callable as follows:

```
 white[BISHOP].row = 3;
 white[BISHOP].col = 2;
```

Answer (score 1):

Aside the refactor proposed by @dbush (which I think it is the correct path to follow), I'm surprised no one has proposed a solution using `union`s.

```
struct A {
    int row;
    int col;
};
struct B {
    int row;
    int col;
};
enum types_t {
    TYPE_A = 0,
    TYPE_B = 1
};
union possible_values_t {
    struct A a;
    struct B b;
};
struct array_t {
    enum types_t t;
    union possible_values_t value;
};

struct array_t arr[2] = {{TYPE_A, {0,0}}, {TYPE_B, {5,4}}};
```

The pro is that, assuming a big array, you waste less memory. The cons is that you need to declare more types (although it can be solved with some macro programming).

Answer (score 0):

You can either use an array of void pointers and then interpret what it is pointing to, or you can use a union of structs, for example:

```
struct Master {
    int whatisthis;
    union {
        struct {
            int i;
            //...
        } s1;
        struct {
            char *s;
            //...
        } s2;
    } u;
} x;
```

the int `whatisthis` can hold e.g. a 0 or a 1 to indicate the union contains s1 or s2.